# Ruby on Rails - Active record loaded records scopes vs collection methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have been working on a large scale rails application and have come across several cases related to performance working with scopes in active record.
For example, if i have two models **Drawing** and **Shape**,
Drawing has many Shapes -> `has_many :shapes`
and shapes have a scope

```
scope :squares, -> { where type: 'Square' }
```

Now, in a complex logic in drawing.rb where i have shapes already loaded, if i use scope like this in **drawing.rb**, 
`shapes.squares`
active record again sends a query to Backend, but to prevent that, i need to make a separate method which filters loaded objects like this

```
def self.filter_squares(shapes)
   shapes.filter(&:is_square?)
end
```

but that makes code difficult to maintain, is there a way to merge scope and loaded objects collection method

Comment: First I am not certain where `filter_squares` is located nor why it appears to be defined at the class instance level; however if this was to be located at an instance level I think this is a very viable option and does not lack any maintainability if you think of it in a larger scope. For example rather than `filter_squares` I would recommend defining the following in `Drawing`:  `def filter_shapes(shape); shapes.select {|s| s.type == shape};end` this has substantial applicability and is very maintainable as it has no direct reference to any particular shape.

Comment: if `shapes` is not loaded then it will load them and filter otherwise it will filter in place.